# SQL delete rows not in another table

Tags: oracle, sql-delete

I'm looking for a good SQL approach (Oracle database) to fulfill the next requirements:

1. Delete rows from **Table A**  that are not present in **Table B.**
2. Both tables have identical structure
3. Some fields are **nullable**
4. Amount of columns and rows is huge (more 100k rows and 20-30 columns to compare)
5. Every single field of every single row needs to be compared from **Table A** against **table B.**
6. Such requirement is owing to a process that must run every day as changes will come from **Table B**.

In other words: **Table A Minus Table B** => Delete the records from the **Table A**

```
delete from Table A
           where (field1, field2, field3) in
                 (select field1, field2, field3
                    from Table A

                  minus
                  select field1, field2, field3
                    from Table B);
```

It's very important to mention that a normal **MINUS** within **DELETE** clause fails as does not take the nulls on nullable fields into consideration (unknown result for oracle, then no match).

I also tried **EXISTS** with success, but I have to use NVL function to replace the nulls with dummy values, which I don't want it as I cannot guarantee that the value replaced in NVL will not come as a valid value in the field.

Does anybody know a way to accomplish such thing? Please remember **performance and nullable** fields as "a must".

Thanks ever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decode` finds sameness (even if both values are null):

```
decode( field1, field2, 1, 0 ) = 1
```

To delete rows in table1 not found in table2:

```
delete table1 t
 where t.rowid in (select t1.rowid
                     from table1 t1
                     left outer join table2 t2
                       on decode(t1.field1, t2.field1, 1, 0) = 1
                      and decode(t1.field2, t2.field2, 1, 0) = 1
                      and decode(t1.field3, t2.field3, 1, 0) = 1
                      /* ... */
                      where t2.rowid is null /* no matching row found */
                      )
```

to use existing indexes

```
                      ...
                      left outer join table2 t2
                      on (t1.index_field1=t2.index_field1 or 
                          t1.index_field1 is null and t2.index_field1 is null)
                      and ...
```

Comment: will try and let you know ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use a left outer join and test for null in your where clause

delete a
  from a
       left outer join b on a.x = b.x 
where b.x is null

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly such "where b.x is null":
What I want is to compare a.x to b.x where the a.x might be null and the b.x might be NOT null and the other way around. Such situation (compare null against something not null) should be identified either way as "not match". Do you know what I mean?

Comment: You can extend the above to join on all desired fields - coalesce allows you to cope with nulls i.e.

where 
coalesce(a.x, 'zzUnlikelyValue') = coalesce(b.x, 'zzUnlikelyValue')

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered ORALCE SQL `MERGE` statement?

Comment: Yes I have, actually I have a MERGE statement but in order to delete a row needs to be updated (which I do not want as such update will "trigger" an oracle trigger which copies rows to a history table + another trigger to copy deleted rows to the history table, which means copying the row twice in a delete operation.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bulk operation for huge number of records. Performance wise it will be faster.

And use join between two table to get rows to be delete. Nullable columns can be compared with some default value.

Also, if you want Table A to be similar as Table B, why don't you truncate table A and then insert data from table b

Comment: Thank you but:
- I'm already using Bulk to fill table B (the one to compare to).
- Join is fine, but I want to avoid the nullable comparison with default values (it's dangerous as you don't know what might come and potential misleading matches might happen).
- I can not truncate as I don't really want Table A similar to Table B because there will come also updates on existing rows.

Comment: but i guess you have to give default value for nullable columns otherwise I don't see any other ways. And you can give any weird value as default val

Comment: Thank you. I'm still trying to avoid default value for nullable. I can't believe oracle does not provide an elegant way to do such thing, like comparing string.empty or something like that, like other languages do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you the same PK field available on each table...(Having a PK or some other unique key is critical for this.)

```
    create table table_a (id number, name varchar2(25), dob date);

    insert into table_a values (1, 'bob', to_date('01-01-1978','MM-DD-YYYY'));

    insert into table_a values (2, 'steve', null);

    insert into table_a values (3, 'joe', to_date('05-22-1989','MM-DD-YYYY'));

    insert into table_a values (4, null, null);

    insert into table_a values (5, 'susan', to_date('08-08-2005','MM-DD-YYYY'));

    insert into table_a values (6, 'juan', to_date('11-17-2001', 'MM-DD-YYYY'));

    create table table_b (id number, name varchar2(25), dob date);

    insert into table_b values (1, 'bob', to_date('01-01-1978','MM-DD-YYYY'));

    insert into table_b values (2, 'steve',to_date('10-14-1992','MM-DD-YYYY'));

    insert into table_b values (3, null, to_date('05-22-1989','MM-DD-YYYY'));

    insert into table_b values (4, 'mary', to_date('12-08-2012','MM-DD-YYYY'));

    insert into table_b values (5, null, null);

    commit;

    -- confirm minus is working
    select id, name, dob 
    from   table_a
    minus
    select id, name, dob
    from   table_b;

    -- from the minus, re-query to just get the key, then delete by key
    delete table_a where id in (
        select id from (
            select id, name, dob 
            from   table_a
            minus
            select id, name, dob
            from   table_b)
    );

    commit;

    select * from table_a;
```

But, if at some point in time, tableA is to be reset to the same as tableB, why not, as another answer suggested, truncate tableA and select all from tableB.

100K is not huge.  I can do ~100K truncate and insert on my laptop instance in less than 1 second.

Comment: As I said before, the MINUS does not work with nullable fields. On the other hand, TableA will never has to be reset to the same content as TableB

Comment: I'm using 11G Express locally and 12C via livesql.oracle.com.  `MINUS` does work with null fields.  I can provide example if necessary.

Comment: Yeah would be great to have such example. Can you copy the script? Try the next scenarios (the ones which does not work to me) if possible:
-At least 1 field nullable in the table(s) definition.
-Fill the data in such a way that a row in TableA has a nullable field with NULL and TableB with something, for example 'test data'.
-Fill the data in such a way that a row in TableA has a nullable field with NULL and TableB with NULL too.
If you try to delete the rows in TableA which are not in TableB under the above conditions, It should not work, not at least to me. THX ever

Comment: Found something that might be the problem: 
Table B does not have PK.
Can this affect to the delete operation if the minus still works anyhow separately?

Comment: Any unique key would work, single column or composite, but preferably on not null columns, or you'll just be back where you started with dealing with NVL and such.

Answer (score 0):

```
> DELETE FROM purchase WHERE clientcode NOT IN (
>     SELECT clientcode FROM client );
```

This deletes the rows from the purchase table whose clientcode are not in the client table. The clientcode of purchase table references the clientcode of client table.

> `DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE FIELD1 NOT IN (SELECT CLIENT1 FROM TABLE2);`

Comment: Your answer does not directly address the question, as far as I can understand it.